# How to change attribute value from an entity (iphone)?

Tags: iphone, core-data

my question is, I have an entity which contains an integer attribute value, that its initially value is 0,   how can I update this attribute value? in specific what I have is a button, and whenever the button is pressed I need the attribute value to be updated?

I appreciate any help.!

Comment: What does your question have to do with your title?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a method -(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id) sender in the .m file in which you want to update the value.
there you need to increment entity.atributevalue++;